# Cannot access class properties inside a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I started learning node.js and I am currently struggling with my middleware I wrote in node.js. It should be an Error handler. The problem is that I cannot access properties I defined inside constructor method. I get this error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
notFound(/[irrelevant]/src/middleware/ErrorHandler.js:12:8)*

This is my code:

ErrorHandler.js

```
class ErrorHandler {
    
    constructor() {
        this.response = {
            success: false,
            errorMessage: '',
            status: 0
        }
    }

    notFound(req, res, next) {
        this.response.errorMessage = 'Not Found'
        this.response.status = 404
        res.status(404).send(this.response)
    }
    
    badRequest(req, res, next) {
        this.response.errorMessage = 'Bad request'
        this.response.status = 400
        res.status(400).send(this.response)
    }
    
}

module.exports = new ErrorHandler()
```

routes.api.js

```
// Import modules
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

// Import controller
const contactController = require('../controllers/ContactController')

// Import error handler
const errorHandler = require('../middleware/ErrorHandler')

router.post('/contact', contactController.index)

// return 404 if no matching routes were found
router.use(errorHandler.notFound)

module.exports = router
```

maybe the code doesn't make any sense, I just need the answer what is causing the error, It's not the code for production purposes.

thank you in advance and have a nice day

Comment: perhaps you need to use `this.notFound = this.notFound.bind(this);` in your constructor - because how the function is being called .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define your methods like this:

```js
notFound = (req, res, next) => {}
```

Comment: Yay, it works now. What is the difference between defining the method like I did and defining methods like an arrow function?

Answer (score 4):

You are passing in a function `errorHandler.notFound` to the middleware. Next time it is called, it will not be bound to the object you exported.

So `this` will not be your `new ErrorHandler()`. In case you want to achieve that you can do two things: [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the method to the `this` in the constructor.

Or use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) as mentioned by @Gogu. Arrow functions take this from their surroundings where they are defined.

Comment: Oh, good to know, I guess I need to reread an article about this keyword. Kinda confuses me. Thank you, I would upvote you if I could.