# Using namespaces inside JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, class, namespaces

I'm building a client for a RESTful API, and in the API there are some modules with the same functions, for example `GetVersion` will return the version of the specific module.

```
https://example.com/core/GetVersion -> 1.1
https://example.com/auth/GetVersion -> 1.8
```

there are multiple modules with the same function/endpoint.

I was wondering how I can implement it into the API class I'm building,
I tried entering all the functions of a module into a namespace but then the functions cannot access methods and properties outside the namespace.

```
class API {
    constructor(config) {
        this.user_id = config.user_id
        this.password = config.password
        this.basePath = `https://${config.server}/`
        this.instance = axios.create({
            httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            })
        });
        this.authToken = undefined
    }

    /******************/
    /* Helper Methods */
    /******************/

    request(endpoint, body, config) {
        const url = this.basePath + endpoint
        config.headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }

        // all requests are POST requests
        return this.instance.post(url, body, config)
            .then(res => {
                return res.data
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }


    /*****************/
    /* Core Services */
    /*****************/
    core = {
        getVersion() {
            return this.request('core-service/getVersion', {}, {}).then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
        }
    }


    /*****************/
    /* Auth Services */
    /*****************/
    auth = {
        getVersion() {
            return this.request('auth-service/getVersion', {}, {}).then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
        }
    }

}

const api_client = new API({
    user_id: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    server: 'example.com'
})

api_client.core.getVersion()
api_client.auth.getVersion()
```

But I get the error

```
return this.request('core-service/getVersion', {}, {}).then(res => {
            ^
TypeError: this.request is not a function
```

What is the best practice to use in order to get different namespaces inside the same class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the same problem as I have :(

Comment: It is the same issue. Classes are constructor functions. Bind the correct this version in the constructor. Another helpful question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235237/cannot-access-class-properties-inside-a-method

Comment: Yeah you were right, thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the methods in the namespace to

```
getVersion: () => {***}
```

and it works now.

Comment: Just be aware that these methods only exist when the object is instantiated with `new`. They will not exist on the prototype.